# Electronic mail-merge

Tags: tools

This is not strictly a TeX/LaTeX/ConTeXt question, nevertheless this is probably the best place to ask.

For the people who don't know: mail merge is a standard functionality in a word processor that allows to send personalized documents to a list of people (usually from some kind of a database). One can send such documents via snail mail or via e-mail.

I've seen many packages/tools to generate the documents with LaTeX for printing and then sending them via snail mail.

What I want to do, is to send the documents via email, as PDF attachments. LibreOffice has such an option. Unfortunately, as is the case for word processors, the generated documents are of rather poor typographic quality.

Now comes the question. Has anyone seen/used a tool that might help with this task but with PDF documents compiled with TeX and friends? I have something in mind:

- Generate *tex files using Python and Jinja
- Compile *tex files using TeX and make (or rather: latexmk)
- Send the resulting *pdf files with python and its email library

Still, as a lazy human being I would rather not write this from scratch. Can someone point me to an existing solution?

Comment: you should clarify what is your starting point; plain text ? html ?

Comment: I don't think this is relevant, but I want to recreate in LaTeX a typical corporate correspondence, with headers, footers, colors etc. It's not the "how to write the template tex file" part I am after. Let's say that my starting point is a template (La)Tex file (in any definition of template that you wish).

Comment: Do you have many changes from one document to the next?

Comment: Not that many – address, salutation, talk title etc. This is to be used for a big conference in mathematics, so additional flexibility is a plus (think "parallel sessions program" etc.).

Comment: I think best place for asking this question is a python forum or a general programming forum, since it has nearly nothing to do with LaTex, does it?